# How can I listen to onTabReselected in a TabLayout bound to a ViewPager?

Tags: android

So I'm using [TabLayout.setupWithViewPager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html#setupWithViewPager(android.support.v4.view.ViewPager)) to make my tabs swipable. In addition I want special functionality attached to a [tabReselcted](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener.html#onTabReselected(android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.Tab)) event on the tabs - normally implemented by adding a `onTabSelectedListener`. The TabLayout can only have one at a time though - the ViewPager now owns that event pipe. How can I solve this conflict?

Anyone have a good solution where I still can use the convenience method `setupWithViewPager`? If not, solve it by a minimal amount of line of codes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using `TabLayout.ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener`. It contains necessary calls back to the provided `ViewPager` so that the tab position is kept in sync. It has `onTabReselected` method you are looking for and is designed to work with `ViewPager`. Find the documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener.html).

Answer (score 1):

that should not be happening if you add the `onTabSelectedListener` after the `TabLayout.setupWithViewPager`.

I just tested it. Are you doing it in this order?

Edit:
Do the following if the fragments don't change:

> public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
>                   pager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition()); }

Comment: Yes. Did you test changing tabs after doing that? The fragments do not change. edit: ...by using the tab buttons

Comment: I've edited my answer because you are right. Fragment don't change. But you can hack it and force them to change.